# How to handle multiple Entitymanagers via OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter on Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have looked over the code of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter and I noticed it looks for one entityManagerFactoryBeanName defined on my Spring context. I do have a  setter to adjust a different bean name case I wanted.

But let's suppose that I had on my application multiple EntityManagers, one for each of my DataSources defined. Spring can define repositories to lead data for those EntityManagers, but how can I inform the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter about this behavior?

It seems the code is only ready to treat one EntityManager by time, so I would not be able to keep lazy data for different repositories on my application.

Is there any way to set it up? I'd appreciate any idea.

***OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter source code:***
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java#OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over many codes, I found out we need to create a filter for each entity manager with your datasource. So if we have a context root application, we will have many filters being applied for this context.